# Add Cloud Map service to Application Load Balancer created by ApplicationLoadBalancedFargateService

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-fargate

I've got the following Fargate service created by an ecs pattern. The CloudMap I create here only points to the underlying task which is a private IP and runs on port 8080 (Tomcat). The ALB forwards properly from 80->8080. How can I get the DNS to properly route to the task? Can I get the DNS service to route directly to the ALB?

```
    const service = new ecs_patterns.ApplicationLoadBalancedFargateService(this, 'MyAppWebstartFargateService', {
      serviceName: "myapp-service",
      cluster: cluster,
      cpu: 512,
      memoryLimitMiB: 2048,
      cloudMapOptions: {
        name: "myapp",
        containerPort: 8080,
        cloudMapNamespace: namespace,
        dnsRecordType: svc_dsc.DnsRecordType.A,
        dnsTtl: Duration.seconds(300),
      },
      desiredCount: 1,
      publicLoadBalancer: false,
      securityGroups: [sg],
      listenerPort: 80,
      openListener: true,
      healthCheckGracePeriod: Duration.seconds(300),
      targetProtocol: elbv2.ApplicationProtocol.HTTP,
      protocol: elbv2.ApplicationProtocol.HTTP,
      enableExecuteCommand: true,
      taskImageOptions: {
        containerName: "myapp-container",
        containerPort: 8080,
        enableLogging: true,
        image: ecs.ContainerImage.fromEcrRepository(repository, "latest"),
      },
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out! I needed to call registerLoadBalancer on the Cloud Map service and give it the resulting LB from the Fargate pattern. Hope this helps someone down the road b/c I could not find any solution to this exact use case.

```
 const namespace = svc_dsc.PrivateDnsNamespace.fromPrivateDnsNamespaceAttributes(this, "MyAppCloudMapNamespace", {
      namespaceArn: "*****************",
      namespaceId: "999999999999999",
      namespaceName: "mydomain.com"
    });

    const mapService = new svc_dsc.Service(this, 'MyAppCloudMapService', {
      namespace: namespace,
      dnsRecordType: svc_dsc.DnsRecordType.A,
      dnsTtl: Duration.seconds(300),
      name: "myapp", 
      routingPolicy: svc_dsc.RoutingPolicy.WEIGHTED,
      loadBalancer: true // Important! If you choose WEIGHTED but don't set this, the routing policy will default to MULTIVALUE instead
    });

    const service = new ecs_patterns.ApplicationLoadBalancedFargateService(this, 'MyAppWebstartFargateService', {
      serviceName: "myapp-service",
      cluster: cluster,
      cpu: 512,
      memoryLimitMiB: 2048,
      desiredCount: 1,
      publicLoadBalancer: false,
      securityGroups: [sg],
      listenerPort: 80,
      openListener: true,
      healthCheckGracePeriod: Duration.seconds(300),
      targetProtocol: elbv2.ApplicationProtocol.HTTP,
      protocol: elbv2.ApplicationProtocol.HTTP,
      enableExecuteCommand: true,
      taskImageOptions: {
        containerName: "myapp-container",
        containerPort: 8080,
        enableLogging: true,
        image: ecs.ContainerImage.fromEcrRepository(repository, "latest"),
      },
    });

    mapService.registerLoadBalancer("MyAppLoadBalancer", service.loadBalancer);
```

Comment: Hmm when we tried this approach we kept getting a "ServiceId length must be less than 64 characters" when we tried to new up the Cloud Discovery service.